# Django form to update an object doesn't keep files

Tags: python, django, forms, file

So I'm working on a portfolio site, and I've got a form called Work that represents the works in the portfolio. A Work has an M2M field for normal images, and one ImageField for the main image that is to be used for thumbnails etc.

My problem is the following, when I go to the update view I created for Work, the old Image (that is already in the database) is listed in the form, but no in the field itself. It says current: [name of the image], and then the regular filefield with label `edit`.

I don't want the user to only be able to update a work if they upload the image again. How do I pass the current image to the form?

```
#models.py
class Work(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    image = models.ImageField( upload_to="images" )

#forms.py
class Meta:
    model = Work
    exclude = ('slug',)

#views.py
def workEdit(request, pk):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = WorkForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_work = form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect("/portfolio/beheer/werk")
    else:
        print(form)
        print(form.errors)
    else:
        work = get_object_or_404(Work, pk=pk)
        form = WorkForm(request.POST ,request.FILES, instance=work)



context = {

    'form': form,

}
return render(request, 'submit.html', context)
```

Comment: That *is* in the form, and doesn't need to be uploaded again. It's already what you want. (Browsers don't let you pre-populate a file upload field, for security reasons.)

Comment: If i click 'update' (a button i created), I've lost the previous image if I haven't uploaded a new one. How can this be solved?

Comment: Well, the way you have the code now, *everything* will be recreated on save - because you're not passing the `instance` attribute when you instantiate the form on POST.

Comment: That fixed it completely, moved the get_or_404 to the first line of the function view. Thanks a lot.